# How to do a Postgresql group aggregation: 2 fields using one to select the other

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table - Data - of rows, simplified, like so:

```
Name,Amount,Last,Date
A,16,31,1-Jan-2014
A,27,38,1-Feb-2014
A,12,34,1-Mar-2014
B,8,37,1-Jan-2014
B,3,38,1-Feb-2014
B,17,39,1-Mar-2014
```

I wish to group them similar to:

```
select Name,sum(Amount),aggr(Last),max(Date) from Data group by Name
```

For aggr(Last) I want the value of 'Last' from the row that contains max(Date)

So the result I want would be 2 rows

```
Name,Amount,Last,Date
A,55,34,1-Mar-2014
B,28,39,1-Mar-2014
```

i.e. in both cases, the value of Last is the one from the row that contained 1-Mar-2014

The query I'm actually doing is basically the same, but with many more sum() fields and millions of rows, so I'm guessing an aggregate function could avoid multiple extra requests each group of incoming rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select Name, sum(Amount),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Last end) as Last,
       max(date)
from (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) d
group by Name;
```

Comment: Yep that seems to solve it - it also covers the requirement of not reading data multiple times which is pretty important since the live system is currently up to around 34mil records. I'll post my actual query once I'm sure it's all OK with a bit more testing, so others can see it, since it is a fraction more complex than the example I gave.